# Why AWS distributes private key for passwordless authentication?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, ssh, openssl

AWS provides access to EC2 by downloading the private key(`.pem`) into management host that connects to EC2.

AWS uses `openssl` tool

Key providers generally provide public key but not private key, because with keypairs, one can encrypt either with public key or private key and decrypt with other key, as shown below:

```
$ openssl genrsa -out mykey 2048

$ cp mykey privatekey

$ openssl rsa -in mykey -pubout -out publickey 

$ rm mykey

$ # Encrypt with public key

$ echo "the cat sat on the mat" | open ssl rsautl -encrypt -pubin -inkey publickey > ciphertxt

$ # cat cipher.txt

$ # cat cipher.txt | openssl rsautl -decrypt -inkey privatekey
```

---

1) 
Why AWS distributes private key instead of public key? for secure communication...

2) 
Key pair is mainly to secure communication on the wire, but not authenticate user, to access a resource in AWS.

`ssh -i something.pem user@ec2-public-dns-name`

How does distribution of a key solve authentication problem? key can be stolen by any wrong person...Why AWS allow ssh login to EC2 without a password?

Comment: How would you login with the public key?

Comment: You answered yourself: "Why AWS distributes private key? for ssh passwordless access". "for SSH passwordless access" is the answer to the question "Why AWS distributes private key?". Without it, you could not authenticate.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/154984/whats-the-benefit-of-using-asymmetric-keys-over-passwords

Comment: @deceze It says: "Protect your private key with a secure password."

Comment: @tkausl Query edited for your question...

Comment: @deceze I have migrated to infosecu. Please delete this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please re-phrase your question.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html

Passwordless access requires that a copy of the *public* key must be placed on the target server; you keep the *private* key ... well ... private.

The communications you send are being encrypted by your private key, which only you have, and the remote host finds that it is able to decrypt them using one of the public keys that it has.  (Which necessarily means that it must be coming from you ... the only holder of the corresponding private key.)  The remote never has your private key.